# How to write Vmax in Latex

Tags: latex

I would like to write `Vmax` where the `V` is large and `max` is quite smaller in Latex. I tried `$V_max$`. It shows the `a` and `x` bigger than the `m` as shown in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I want the `a` and `x` to be the same size of the `m`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use curly brackets to apply a modifier like subset/superset for more than one letter:

```
$V_{max}$
```

Comment: You shouldn't use math mode for multi-letter expressions, this will mess up the kerning. It would be better to wrap it in `\text{...}` from the amsmath package.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes, subscripts or superscripts with more than one character must be *grouped* within braces (`$V_{max}$`). Further, a syntax that would work within math delimiters is `V_{\textnormal{max}}`. Like:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

$V_{\textnormal{max}}$

\end{document}
```

Also, the macro `text` from package `amsmath` makes the subscript better proportioned:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$V_{\text{max}}$

\end{document}
```

Here's the output with the two methods:

[image: screenshot of output]